# Trying a best solution?

Tags: java, swing, jpa, arraylist, jtable

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I have 2 java class of domain. Graduacao and Aluno, in Graduacao I have an attribute "graus" that is a Collection.
In Aluno class, I have collection attribute "List graduacao". 
I add the Graduacao in a JComboBox about ComboBoxModel and when user selected a Graduacao I have a JList that show the "graus" of Graduacao.

What I need is get Graduacao and graus that user choose and add to Aluno and persist after show results in a JTable with AbstractTableModel.

I'm trying this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="graduacao")
public class Graduacao {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
    private String graduacao;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="graduacao_grau", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_graduacao"))
    @Column(name="grau")    
    private List<String> graus;

    //get and set


@Entity
@Table(name="aluno")
public class Aluno {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    //informacoes gerais
    @NotNull
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;
    private String nomePai;
    private String nomeMae; 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtNascimento;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtCadastro;
    private String status;
    private String observacoes;

    //logradouro
    private String endereco;    
    private String bairro;
    private String complemento;
    private String cidade;
    private String cep;    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EstadoBrasileiro uf;

    //contato
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="telefone_aluno", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_aluno"))
    @Column(name="telefone")
    private List<String> telefones;
    private String email;

    //graduacao
    @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name="id_aluno")
    private List<Graduacao> graduacao;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataGraduou;

    //federacao
    @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name="id_federacao")
    private List<Federacao> federacao;

    //get and set
```

here the print
[image]

/** edit */
I solved the problem, here the project: http://www.4shared.com/zip/1Gbj-IZLce/project_example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete example is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. Two approaches are common, although neither is simple:

- Create a custom [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) that uses JPA queries and entities to implement the methods required by `AbstractTableModel`; a very simple example using `JComboBox` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513); a complete `TableModel` example with pagination is shown [here](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/08/17/jtable-and-jpa-pagination/).
- Use `org.jdesktop.beansbinding`, shown [here](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/08/18/jtable-beans-binding-and-jpa-pagination/) and mentioned [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/beans-binding-dummies) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24935372/230513).

A number of ancillary links related to this topic are shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3424872/230513).

Comment: I understand. But my problem is when user choose Graduacao in JComboBox and "graus" in JList. I need get all choice of user and create a another List to Aluno. I can get JComboBox choice and JList choice, my problem is to create another List. See my entity Graduacao has an attribute "graus", this attribute is a List<String> and receive annotation ElementCollection and my entity Aluno has an attribute "graduacao" this attribute is a List<Graduacao>.

Comment: You'll need to write a JPA query that fetches the rows in `Aluno` for the selected `Graduacao` and `Graus`; sorry, I don't understand your data model well enough to be more specific.

Comment: `Aluno` looks like a `JTable`, rather than a `JList`; in either case you would construct the corresponding model using the query results.

Comment: ahhhh....I think understand you. I need create other model with results and setModel to my JTable.

Comment: Yes, this simplified [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) may offer guidance.

Comment: but how to I persist Aluno with List<Graduacao> and "graus" that user choice ?

Comment: You'll need to update the affected rows in `Aluno` in your table model's implementation of `setValueAt()`.

Comment: for example:

Graduacao g = (Graduacao)cbx_graduacao.getSelectedItem();
List<String> grausList = g.getGraus(jlist_graus.getSelectedIndex());
List<Graduacao> graduacaoList = new ArrayList<Graduacao>();
graduacaoList.add(g);
Aluno bean = new Aluno();
bean.setGraduacao(graduacaoList);
AlunoDAO().persist(bean);

This is your suggestion ?

Comment: When a given `TableCellEditor` [concludes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513), `setValueAt()` will be called for the single updated cell; you may be able to persist just that value. Will you be adding rows to the table?

Comment: hello, I solved the problem. If you know how I did here the project: http://www.4shared.com/zip/1Gbj-IZLce/project_example.html . Thanks my friend :D

Comment: @FernandoPaiva: You are welcome; you may want to edit your question to show the link to the project.